# Put JTextComponent and JComboBox in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have List and List and I need to create JTable with theese two columns. I am confused with model, can anybofy show me how to do that please, I am new to swing and Java ?

Comment: Show you how to do what specifically?  If you haven't done so, have you gone through the Swing tutorials on how to create JTables and table models?  If you have, then please clarify your question for us since as written it is overly broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [check out my answer to some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698422/custom-classes-and-jlists/5704738#5704738). Where I have presented a simple table model often use.

In your case you would create data in a following way:

```
//I assumed here list 1 and 2 have the same sizes
List<Object> list1 = getList1();
List<Object> list2 = getList2();
int rNo = list1.size();
List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>(rNo);
int cNo = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < rNo; i++)
{
     List<Object> r = new ArrayList<Object>(cNo);
     r.add(list1.get(i));
     r.add(list2.get(i));
     data.add(r);
}
tm.setData(data);
```

Comment: this AbstractTableModel missed some "Usefull" methods and Model#fire..... TableStructureChanged(), TableDataChanged() and TableCellUpdated(int row, int col);

Comment: @mKorbel understood. Well it has default ones from its super class. As to other useful methods `@Override
 public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c)
 {
  return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
 }`  Thanks to this one you would get check boxes in a cell where you use boolean instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

No worries, just set your desired component as a cell editor for that column. Simple ain't it.

**Example Snippet**

```
public class JTextFieldCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {    
    JTextField textField;    
    public JTextFieldCellEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
        textField = (JTextField) getComponent();   
    }
}
```

Then include it like below,

```
TableColumn column = myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
column.setCellEditor(new JTextFieldCellEditor());
```

**Further reading:**

Here is your best bet, [Swing tutorial for JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).